# How to convert Base64 to Image in Scriptable App

Tags: javascript, base64, scriptable

I want to convert the Base64 I get from an API into an image in the iOS scriptable app.
Here is my current code:

```
let image = Image.data(Data.fromBase64String(response.icon))
```

How could I convert the base64 into an image?

The error:

```
2021-08-19 12:31:07: Error on line 20:23: TypeError: Image.data is not a function. (In 'Image.data(Data.fromBase64String(response.icon))', 'Image.data' is undefined)
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Isn't it doing what you're asking for? If there are any errors or wrong results, you should describe that in the question.

Comment: Whoops sorry, just updated it. Sadly it doesn’t do what I want it to do and throws an undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call the correct initialiser for Image ( It’s .fromData ) :

```
let image = Image.fromData(Data.fromBase64String(response.icon))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let image = await new Request("data:image/png;base64,AAAAAAA").loadImage()
```